# How to prevent text messages from my iPhone to my iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, messages, sms

My text messages from my iPhone are appearing on our iPad, how do I stop that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I stop my text messages and emails from showing on my 5yr old's iPad?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94174/how-do-i-stop-my-text-messages-and-emails-from-showing-on-my-5yr-olds-ipad)

Comment: @Tetsujin Not at all. The older question was before iOS 8 and was about mixing iMessage accounts and the lack of an opt out for the mapping of SMS to iMessage. This is a new issue enabled on iOS 8 whereby SMS and phone calls can be received on other OS X and iOS devices that are not cellular devices themselves.

Comment: @bmike sure - I was assuming iMessage rather than SMS, though it's not truly clear from the OP.

Answer (score 1):

On the iPad open the settings app. In FaceTime turn off **iPhone Cellular Calls**.